# Check whether a word is in a text box regardless of case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out whether a text box has a given word, regardless of case. For example, how can I determine whether a given text box, `#TextBox`, has the word `"hello"` in it?

```
var specialwords = ['hello','Hello','HELLO']; //special words here

$('#TextBox').keydown(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.split(" ");
    var newtext = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        // code to check words
    }
    $("#check").html(newtext);
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your goal? I tried to answer your question below, but I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @royhowie to check a typed word whether its uppercase, lowercase or a combo.

Comment: So you want to know whether a textbox has a given word, regardless of case?

Comment: Not sure what all you want to do once you find said words, but a regexp should handle it quickly and easily. Example below.

Comment: @Ben I am looking for the shortest and simplest way to add/modify my code without changing it on a whole.

Comment: I think that my example below will work well then.

Comment: @Ben  I did "text.toLowerCase().split(" ");" to modify the code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check whether a text box has a given word, irrespective of case, is to convert the text box to lowercase, then split by spaces and find the `indexOf` the word.

```
var word = "hello".toLowerCase();    // make sure this word is lowercase

$("#TextBox").keydown(function () {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase().split(" ");
    if (text.indexOf(word) > -1) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // word is not in the text box
    }
})
```

If you want to check for an array of words, `specialWords`, wrap the if block in a for loop. This would be `O(n²)` complexity, but that should be fine, as long as your input isn't extremely long<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>we're talking thousands upon thousands of words long for it to matter.</sup>

Comment: The text would be limited to 15-20 words

Comment: @X10nD Then it wouldn't matter. It would only slow down for extremely large inputs.

Comment: All I did was "text.toLowerCase().split(" ");" to modify my code.  Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkAlphaCase(alpha) {
  if (alpha == alpha.toLowerCase()) {
    alert('LowerCase');
  } else if (alpha == alpha.toUpperCase()) {
    alert('UppperCase');
  } else {
    alert('MixedCase');

  }

}


checkAlphaCase('ANIR');
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    
  
  var specialwords = ['hello','Hello','HELLO'];//special words here

            $('#TextBox').keydown(function() {
             //alert(this);
                var text = $(this).val().trim();
              console.log(text);
              //  text = text.trim().split(" ");
                var newtext = "";
                var up=0,low=0;
                for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
                  if(text[i]==" ")
                    continue;
                  else{
                  if(text[i].trim()==text[i].trim().toLowerCase())
                    low++;
                   if(text[i].trim()==text[i].trim().toUpperCase())
                    up++;
                    }
                }
              if(up>0 && low>0)
                newtext="mix case";
              else if(up>0)
                newtext="Upper case"; 
              else if(low>0)
                newtext="Lower case"

                $("#check").html(newtext);
            });
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="TextBox">
<div id="check"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a case insensitive regex with all the words like this:

```
RegExp("\\b(?:" + specialwords.join("|") + ")\\b", "i")
```

then you can use it against each word. I am not sure what you are doing with the words once you identify them ... I will assume for the purpose of my code snippet that you are ignoring them from the text.

```
var specialwords = ['hello','world','pizza']; //special words here
var swr = RegExp("\\b(?:" + specialwords.join("|") + ")\\b", "i")

$('#TextBox').keydown(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = text.split(" ");
    var newtext = [];
    for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
        if (!text.match(swr)) {
            newtext.push(text)
        }
    }
    $("#check").html(newtext.join(" "));
});
```

Using the `\b` as a word delimiter in regexp you can also check the whole text without breaking up the words if you want.

```
var specialwords = ['hello','world','pizza']; //special words here
var swr = RegExp("\\b(?:" + specialwords.join("|") + ")\\b", "i")

$('#TextBox').keydown(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var newtext = text.replace(swr, "");
    $("#check").html(newtext);
});
```